# Does it have any sense using hasOne and belongsTo at the same time?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have a scenario like the following:

```
Account.belongsTo(models.Address, {
    as: 'address',
    foreignKey: { name: 'addressId', field: 'address_id' },
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT'
});

Address.hasOne(models.Account, {
    as: 'account',
    foreignKey: { name: 'addressId', field: 'address_id' },
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT'
});
```

I don't get it if I should use them both or not. BelongsTo probably yes but it's necessary to use also hasOne?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what context you're calling this code in?

Comment: yes sure. I'm calling this code during the definition of the associations inside a definition of the models Account and Address

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule: Yes, you should define both.

From a practical perspective, you should define the association for a model `Foo` if you ever need to call the `fooInstance.setBar` and `fooInstance.getBar` methods on an instance. You should also define the association if you ever need to do `Foo.find(..., { include: [Bar] });`.

From a conceptual perspective, you should ask if it makes sense for the relationship to be bidirectional. If a Foo belongs to a Bar, does that mean that a Bar has one (or many) Foo's? Usually the answer to that question is going to be yes.

Answer (score 1):

Doing both the definitions allows you to select the address of an account and the account of an address.

```
models.account.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.address
  }]
});

models.address.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.account
  }]
});
```